# Agregar estilo CSS hasta cierto elemento hijo

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy intentado que el color PINK solo se aplique hasta el elemento 7 **div** que contiene clase children, habia pensado en un **:nth-child** pero no he logrado implementarlo

```css
.padre .children {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    
  }

.padre .children *.children:last-of-type {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="children">
      <div class="children">
        <div class="children">
          <div class="children">
            <div class="children">
              <div class="children">
                <div class="children">
                  <div class="children">
                    <div class="children">
                      <div class="children">
                        <div class="children"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dándole un poco la vuelta al razonamiento, lo que puedes hacer es que todos los elementos `.children` sean rosas y crear una regla específica para que a partir del octavo se vuelvan rojos.

Para ello puedes servirte del selector `>` para ir referenciando al **descendiente directo** hasta así llegar a los descendientes del séptimo `.children`.

```css
.padre .children {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: pink;  
}
  
.padre > .children > .children > .children > .children > .children > .children > .children .children {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="children">
      <div class="children">
        <div class="children">
          <div class="children">
            <div class="children">
              <div class="children">
                <div class="children">
                  <div class="children">
                    <div class="children">
                      <div class="children">
                        <div class="children"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba, pensé que había alguna manera mas robusta de hacerlo, pero me funciona !!

Comment: No la hay que yo conozca, por desgracia. `nth-child()` te serviría si todos los elementos `.children` fuesen hermanos y no hijos los unos de los otros. En el caso de elementos descendentes el operador `>` es la única solución que se me ocurre.

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta la respuesta numero 2, podrías evitarte los .children colocando

```css
.padre .children {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.padre > * > * > * > * > * > * > .children * {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes posibilidad de agregar una clase adicional a los elementos que no desea que se aplique PINK? Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
  .padre .children div:not(.no) {
     background-color: pink;  
   }
```

Agregando la clase "no" a los div que no quieras pintar.